# Always using around 96% RAM (4.6GB out of 16GB) Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

On my laptop my RAM is always full. I know I have too many tabs open (around 70) but even after I just boot up my pc and without opening Firefox it quickly climbs to over 90% usage.
The strange thing is that when I go to the Users tab in task manager it says I'm using somewhere between 4 and 5GB which is around 90 to 98% even though I have 16GB installed (see screenshots below). My maths may be off, but I'm pretty sure 4.670GB out of 16GB is 29% and not 96%.

I have already tried to look for a driver that could cause a memory leak, but I can't find a driver that uses more than one GB. My paged pool is also at 1.3GB, which is high, but it doesn't explain the other 8GB I'm missing.

What can be the cause of this and how can I fix this?

edit:
I do not use a virus scanner besides Windows Defender. I do have the free version of malwarebytes for manual scans. I have all scan options toggled on and it didn't detect any problems.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That definitely looks wrong. Have a look at the values in RAMMap or Poolmon and see if there are any obvious candidates. Otherwise reboot your machine and see whether it looks any better then. Not shutdown and restart, do a proper reboot/restart from the power menu.

Comment: Your paged pool is low but your Committed memory is up at 25GB which definitely means some kind of memory hog. Can you go to the details tab in tack manager, right click the column title at the top of the task list, select "choose columns" and show committed memory? If nothing shows there then it may well be a driver leaking memory.